# Using Fixtures vs passing method as argument

Tags: python, pytest

I'm just learning Python and Pytest and came across Fixtures. Pardon the basic question but I'm a bit wondering what's the advantage of using fixtures in Python as you can already pass a method as argument, for example:

```py
def method1():
    return 'hello world'

def method2(methodToRun):
    result = methodToRun()
    return result

method2(method1)
```

What would be the advantage of passing a `@pytest.fixture` object as argument instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One difference is that fixtures pass the result of calling the function, not the function itself. That doesn't answer your question though why you'd want to use `pytest.fixture` instead of just manually calling it, so I'll just list a couple of things.

One reason is the global availability. After you write a fixture in `conftest.py`, you can use it in your whole test suite just by referencing its name and avoid duplicating it, which is nice.

In case your fixture returns a mutable object, `pytest` also handles the new call for you, so that you can be sure that other tests using the same fixture won't change the behavior between each other. If `pytest` didn't do that by default, you'd have to do it by hand.

A big one is that the plugin system of `pytest` uses fixtures to make its functionality available. So if you are a web dev and want to have a mock-server for your tests, you just install `pytest-localserver` and now adding `httpserver`, `httpsserver`, and `smtpserver` arguments to your test functions will inject the fixtures from the library you just installed. This is *incredibly* convenient and intuitive, in particular when compared to injection mechanisms in other languages.

The bottom line is that it is useful to have a single way to include dependencies in your test suits, and `pytest` chooses a fixture mechanism that magically binds itself to function signatures. So while it really is no different from manually inserting the argument, the quality of life things `pytest` adds through it make it worth it.

Answer (score 3):

Fixture are a way of centralizing your test variables, avoid redundancy. If you are confortable with the concept of Dependency Injection, that's basically the same advantages, i.e. python will automatically bind your parameters with the available fixtures so you build tests more quickly by simply asking for what you need.

Also, fixtures enables you to easily parametrize all your tests at once. Which will avoid some cumbersome code if you want to do it by hand. (more info about it on the documentation: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#parametrizing-fixtures)

Some references:

- Official documentation: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html
- Dependency injection: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection